# Windows Installer Rollback install directory files cleanup problem

Tags: windows-installer, c#-2.0

I am facing problem in Windows Installer Rollback functionality. I have created an installer class and it launches custom action [installer type] to create database, If user wants to rollback I used InstallerException with custom message, but if i do so than in the install directory some temp files and CreateDatabase.InstallState file are not removed and these are supposed to be removed.

In the mentioned scenario I want to rollback in such a way that system should be restored to its initial state as it is requirement for Windows 7 logo certification. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create custom action(s) to remove the database and temp files, and set it to only fire during the rollback, of course.

Assuming your custom action is scheduled before the built-in file & directory removal, then the rollback will remove the install directory on its own (but only if the directory is totally empty).